# Cut the image into equal pieces - or just call the part of the image? Flutter - Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to assign a part of a picture into a contender example - an example of a puzzle game. using flutter

Comment: Please provide more info, any code snippet if any.

Comment: https://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/f/images/6x5grid.gif

Comment: https://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/f/images/1-10rec.gif - Or select this part only from the image

Answer (score 0):

Look this is some code how you can do this:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PuzzlePiece extends StatefulWidget {
  final Image image;
  final Size imageSize;
  final int row;
  final int col;
  final int maxRow;
  final int maxCol;

  PuzzlePiece(
      {Key key,
        @required this.image,
        @required this.imageSize,
        @required this.row,
        @required this.col,
        @required this.maxRow,
        @required this.maxCol})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  PuzzlePieceState createState() {
    return new PuzzlePieceState();
  }
}

class PuzzlePieceState extends State<PuzzlePiece> {
  double top;
  double left;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imageWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final imageHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / widget.imageSize.width;
    final pieceWidth = imageWidth / widget.maxCol;
    final pieceHeight = imageHeight / widget.maxRow;

    if (top == null) {
      top = Random().nextInt((imageHeight - pieceHeight).ceil()).toDouble();
      top -= widget.row * pieceHeight;
    }
    if (left == null) {
      left = Random().nextInt((imageWidth - pieceWidth).ceil()).toDouble();
      left -= widget.col * pieceWidth;
    }

    return Positioned(
        top: top,
        left: left,
        width: imageWidth,
        child: ClipPath(
          child: CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: PuzzlePiecePainter(widget.row, widget.col, widget.maxRow, widget.maxCol),
            child: widget.image
          ),
        clipper: PuzzlePieceClipper(widget.row, widget.col, widget.maxRow, widget.maxCol),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// this class is used to clip the image to the puzzle piece path
class PuzzlePieceClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final int row;
  final int col;
  final int maxRow;
  final int maxCol;

  PuzzlePieceClipper(this.row, this.col, this.maxRow, this.maxCol);

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return getPiecePath(size, row, col, maxRow, maxCol);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}

// this class is used to draw a border around the clipped image
class PuzzlePiecePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final int row;
  final int col;
  final int maxRow;
  final int maxCol;

  PuzzlePiecePainter(this.row, this.col, this.maxRow, this.maxCol);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Color(0x80FFFFFF)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0;

    canvas.drawPath(getPiecePath(size, row, col, maxRow, maxCol), paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

// this is the path used to clip the image and, then, to draw a border around it; here we actually draw the puzzle piece
Path getPiecePath(Size size, int row, int col, int maxRow, int maxCol) {
  final width = size.width / maxCol;
  final height = size.height / maxRow;
  final offsetX = col * width;
  final offsetY = row * height;
  final bumpSize = height / 4;

  var path = Path();
  path.moveTo(offsetX, offsetY);

  if (row == 0) {
    // top side piece
    path.lineTo(offsetX + width, offsetY);
  } else {
    // top bump
    path.lineTo(offsetX + width / 3, offsetY);
    path.cubicTo(offsetX + width / 6, offsetY - bumpSize, offsetX + width / 6 * 5, offsetY - bumpSize, offsetX + width / 3 * 2, offsetY);
    path.lineTo(offsetX + width, offsetY);
  }

  if (col == maxCol - 1) {
    // right side piece
    path.lineTo(offsetX + width, offsetY + height);
  } else {
    // right bump
    path.lineTo(offsetX + width, offsetY + height / 3);
    path.cubicTo(offsetX + width - bumpSize, offsetY + height / 6, offsetX + width - bumpSize, offsetY + height / 6 * 5, offsetX + width, offsetY + height / 3 * 2);
    path.lineTo(offsetX + width, offsetY + height);
  }

  if (row == maxRow - 1) {
    // bottom side piece
    path.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY + height);
  } else {
    // bottom bump
    path.lineTo(offsetX + width / 3 * 2, offsetY + height);
    path.cubicTo(offsetX + width / 6 * 5, offsetY + height - bumpSize, offsetX + width / 6, offsetY + height - bumpSize, offsetX + width / 3, offsetY + height);
    path.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY + height);
  }

  if (col == 0) {
    // left side piece
    path.close();
  } else {
    // left bump
    path.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY + height / 3 * 2);
    path.cubicTo(offsetX - bumpSize, offsetY + height / 6 * 5, offsetX - bumpSize, offsetY + height / 6, offsetX, offsetY + height / 3);
    path.close();
  }

  return path;
}
```

I found this code [Here](https://dragosholban.com/2019/02/16/building-a-puzzle-game-using-flutter/) but that part i choose is the one that you send and image and make the pieces, now its importan to know the way it was use to make it i a new Stateful Class receive the Image and some other parameter that you need to look so can customize what do you need, like number of rows and columns, min y max and the image itself, the way its done its with a new class the extends CustomClipper and hits its actually the one that create the pieces cutting making calculations with the number of rows and columns and the width and height of the received image.

Now he is using this like `path.cubicTo(offsetX + width - bumpSize, offsetY + height / 6, offsetX + width - bumpSize, offsetY + height / 6 * 5, offsetX + width, offsetY + height / 3 * 2);` but its to create the puzzle bump form so if you do not need this you can omit it.

You can play around with that code a little bit and see how its gonna fit you needs.

Comment: I was unable to execute. You can only display a code to display X, Y from the image in container or any widget. and thanks